# How can i workaround the scalling problem in firefox?

Tags: firefox

My Problem is that i have to use the scale function. But when i use it this happens

[image: Screenshot]

it forces my object to scrool and it won´t allow it to go over it.

But i want to have it like in the Picture above that my now "Green Box" can go over the object and doesn´t force it to creat a scrollbar

Here is the code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link href="HTML Firefox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>


  <div>

    <div style="position:relative; width: 100px; height: 100px; overflow: auto; background: skyblue; ">
      <div style="position: fixed; width: 40px; height: 40px; background: green; left: 10px; top: 80px; z-index: 99; "></div>
    </div>

    <hr />


    <div style="position:relative; width: 100px; height: 100px; overflow: auto; background-color:brown;scale:1 ">
      <div style="position: fixed; width: 40px; height: 40px; background: blue; left: 10px; top: 200px; z-index: 99; "></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Note: the `<meta>`, `<link>` and `<hr>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in any HTML specification.

Comment: You are also declaring HTML but are using a XHTML namespace. Are you really attempting to use XHTML?